# Sort array based on value JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have an object of this type and I want to sort the `figsList` array in that object based on `createdAt` property (latest first). How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

I want to perform this operation in my NodeJS backend.

```
{
  id,
  name,
  figsList[
    {
      ...
      createdAt: DateTime
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
      createdAt: DateTime
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
      createdAt: DateTime
      ...
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `.sort()` method. `.sort()` takes a callback function, which takes as parameters 2 objects contained in the array. In your case you can try with:

```
figsList.sort((a, b) => (a.createdAt > b.createdAt) ? 1 : -1)
```

When we return a positive value, the function communicates to `sort()` that the object b takes precedence in sorting over the object a. Returning a negative value will do the opposite.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked but with a little change.
`.sort((a, b) => (b.createdAt > a.createdAt) ? 1 : -1)` as I wanted the latest created one at top.

Comment: Yes, my answer will sort the array ascending.

Comment: yes, even changing `1 : -1` to `-1 : 1` sorted it to descending. It worked.